# XCODE Swift2 : Submitting my app

Tags: ios, submission, ios-autolayout

I am ready with the coding and everything. My app is an iPhone app and it looks great in iPhone5, 5S, 6, 6Plus, 6S and 6SPlus but not on iphone4.
There is formatting issue. the buttons are overlapping because of the constraints but they look perfect on iphone5 and above. Similarly it works perfect on iPadPro but not one other iPads. 
My targeted decides are iPhone5 and above. Do you think I still need to fix iphone4 formatting? 
Would apple check on all devices even thought that's not my targeted device?

Thanks

Comment: In my experience, i have to do a size calculation for all button size and image. as i remember, you cannot choose the target devices for your app of distribution .

Answer (score 0):

Yes, your app must work properly on the iPhone 4(s). And it must work properly on all iPads, not just the iPad Pro. Fix it or be rejected.